which thread group or what changes to do in thread group, to send continous data through TCP protocol to server without waiting for the response
I want to do load testing for a server where i will be sending request with data continously.
Requirement: In jmeter , i want to send requests with data(text) through TCP protocol continously for long time and it should not wait for the response of the previous request for sending next request.As server does not send the response, the jmeter should send the request continously.
I used normal thread group with 10 connection with infinite loop and continous re-use for connections(threads) but as the jmeter is waiting for response, connections are active but data is sent only once.
I also tried JSR223 sampler with counter and loop controller but connections are active but request is not sent even once.
below is the script in groovy
`    import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
 // Retrieve the thread number (0-based index)
 int threadNum = ctx.getThreadNum();

 // Calculate the counter value based on the thread number
 int baseCounterValue = 860181068935920;
 int counterValue = baseCounterValue + threadNum;

 log.info("Thread number: " + threadNum + ", Counter value: " + counterValue);

 String dataToSend                 ="\$,Lt4G,LCR,NR,86018106,,L,1,08022024,112732,20.791864,85.261978,13.,225,26,Air4G,28,42,11001,,20  02,298085.8,3477,*";

 log.info("Current counter value: " + dataToSend);


 // Get the sampler from the context
 TCPSampler tcpSampler = new TCPSampler();
 tcpSampler.setServer("dummy server");
 tcpSampler.setPort("4242");
 tcpSampler.setRequestData(dataToSend);


 // Send the request
 tcpSampler.sample();`


I fail to see why do you need Groovy at all, you can use "normal" TCP Sampler and set some minimal timeouts:

Of course the TCP Sampler will fail due to not receiving the response within the given timeout, if you want to mark it as passed you can do it using Response Assertion:

